# How to send automatic email on daily ,weekly and monthly bases?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

How do I send email on daily, weekly and monthly bases using c#.net?

I was thinking of creating a windows service application but I don't know how to do it and if it's the right way to take.

Your thoughts are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really need to send email from .NET application? Other option: send from SQL Server Job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A windows service is probably the best option.

In your service have a timer that fires with whatever resolution you need (every minute/hour/day etc) and on the timer tick even send your emails.

There are [many](http://en.csharp-online.net/Creating_a_.NET_Windows_Service) [tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984464%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) [for](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/2173801/Creating-a-Windows-Service-in-NET.htm) [creating](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/window_service11262005045007am/window_service.aspx) [windows](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/simplewindowsservice.aspx) [services](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_system/services/article.php/c4825) with .NET.

Comment: Isn't this over-engineering? What's wrong with the Windows Task Scheduler?

Answer (score 2):

A Windows service will do the trick.  A good benefit of a Windows service is that it starts up when Windows starts up (or can be set to, anyway).  So the machine can be left fairly unattended (as a good server should) and doesn't need anybody logged into it for the service to run.  So if that's an important consideration for your scenario then perhaps a Windows service would be the way to go.

If you just want to create a console application instead (which can generally be easier to create/test/debug) then you can schedule it with the native Windows task scheduler.  However, unless I'm mistaken, I think a user needs to be logged in to the machine in order for it to run.  At least under certain circumstances.  So a Windows service is probably your best bet for an unattended task.

As for creating the service, Visual Studio should have a project template for that.  The scheduling would be handled with a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the Windows Task Scheduler. [Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) seems to be the right tool, too (never used it though).

Answer (score 2):

Windows Service is a good choice.

Remember to save state to disk (file or database) because service restart (for example, due to a reboot) is possible. For example, your next email delivery is a week in the future, you have to save that date to disk. So when your server is down due to a power failure 3 days later and recover after another day, your Windows Service can still set the right timer according to the date saved to disk.

Answer (score 1):

Create a console application, which would be launched from the Windows task scheduler.  Creating a windows service is unnecessarily complex, IMO, since you are simply having the program execute in response to time intervals; not other unpredictable external events where you would need a 'listener' type application.  KISS!